# How do I load a view into a variable?

Tags: javascript, view, node.js, express

I need to use websockets to send a view so it can be loaded within a tab. But I can't seem to figure out how to load view into a variable for sending. Seems like the only way to load a view is to call the `response.render()` function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most templating engines can render a template to an in-memory string, which you can then send over your web socket as raw data. Here's the example from [jade](http://jade-lang.com/).

```
var jade = require('jade');

// Render a string
jade.render('string of jade', { options: 'here' });

// Render a file
jade.renderFile('path/to/some.jade', { options: 'here' }, function(err, html){
    // options are optional,
    // the callback can be the second arg
});
```

If you mention specifically which templating engine you are using, we can give specific examples if needed.

Here's [how to do it with EJS](http://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/wiki/Templates):

```
html = new EJS({url: '/template.ejs'}).render(data)
```

Comment: using ejs, is there a similar renderFile method in ejs?

Comment: Updated my answer with some EJS specifics. (There may be more than 1 project called EJS...)

Answer (score 1):

While Peter's solution would work for Jade, I am using EJS. And EJS does not have a renderFile function. So here's a generic way to read the a plain HTML file:

```
s.readFile(__dirname + '/views/tabs/' + data.tab + '/index.ejs', 'utf8', function( err, html )
{
    socket.emit( 'setTabHTML', { tab: data.tab, 'html': html });
});
```